# combine all txt file in a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to combine all the txt files having a header in a folder. I need the header to be written only once.

s1.txt

```
Header
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

s2.txt

```
Header
12
22
32
42
52
62
72
82
```

s3.txt

```
Header
123
223
323
423
523
623
723
823
```

There are two solutions

1: Simple one

```
copy /b *.txt Combined.txt // It writes header each time also
```

2: solution with loop

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
   if not exist Combined.txt (
      copy "%%f" Combined.txt
   ) else (
      for /F  "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%a in ("%%f") do (
         echo %%a>> Combined.txt
      )
   )
)
```

But it is not working properly.

```
Header
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
812  // NEED to start with next line
22
32
42
52
62
72
82
123
223
323
423
523
623
723
823
```

Any idea?? Also other solutions???

Comment: That is because the last line on the first file does not end with a CRLF.

Answer (score 3):

A quite simple solution is to use the [`find` command](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) since this appends a final line-break when needed, so you do not have to particularly take care of that on your own:

```cmd
@echo off
rem /* Use a flag-style variable that indicates the first file,
rem    so we know whether or not we have to apply the header: */
set "FIRST=#"
rem // Write to the output file:
> "Combined.txt" (
    rem /* Loop through all input files, with the order is defined by the file system
    rem    (the used pattern also ensures to does not match the output file): */
    for %%I in ("s*.txt") do (
        rem // Query the flag-style variable:
        if defined FIRST (
            rem // This is the first input file, hence return the whole content:
            < "%%~I" find /V ""
        ) else (
            rem // This is not the first input file, hence exclude the header:
            < "%%~I" find /V "Header"
        )
        rem // Clear the flag-style variable here:
        set "FIRST="
    )
)
```

If the header string (`Header`) may occur within other lines but the headline also, try to replace the command line `< "%%~I" find /V "Header"` by the one `< "%%~I" (set /P ="" & findstr "^")`, although this might cause problems on certain Windows versions as `findstr` might hang (refer to the post [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873)).

---

Here is an approach based on `for /F` loops; the difference to your similar approach is that also the first file is handled by a `for /F` loop, which lets also the last line be terminated by a line-break in the output:

```cmd
@echo off
rem /* Use a flag-style variable that indicates the first file,
rem    so we know whether or not we have to apply the header: */
set "FIRST=#"
rem // Write to the output file:
> "Combined.txt" (
    rem /* Loop through all input files, with the order is defined by the file system
    rem    (the used pattern also ensures to does not match the output file): */
    for %%I in ("s*.txt") do (
        rem // Query the flag-style variable:
        if defined FIRST (
            rem // This is the first input file, hence return the whole content:
            for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%%~I") do (
                echo(%%L
            )
        ) else (
            rem // This is not the first input file, hence exclude the header:
            for /F "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%L in ("%%~I") do (
                echo(%%L
            )
        )
        rem // Clear the flag-style variable here:
        set "FIRST="
    )
)
```

Note that a `for /F` skips blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes that the header is in the first file mentioned. If you are on a supported Windows machine, PowerShell will be available. This may require the current PowerShell 5.1 or higher.

=== Get-CombinedFile.ps1

```
$outFilename = 'C:/src/t/Combined.txt'
$files = @('./s1.txt', './s2.txt', './s3.txt')

Set-Location -Path 'C:/src/t'
Get-Content -Path $files[0] -First 1 |
    Out-File -FilePath $outFilename -Encoding ascii
Get-ChildItem -Path $files |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-Content -Path $_ |
            Select-Object -Skip 1 |
            Out-File -FilePath $outFilename -Encoding ascii -Append
    }
```

Invoke it in a cmd.exe shell or .bat file script.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File 'C:\src\t\Get-CombinedFile.ps1'
```